# Передача параметров в открытую программу на C++

Tags: c++

Как написать простую программу на C++, например, в виде табло, в которую можно передавать параметры, не перезапуская её?

Comment: ipc/socket/перечитывание файла

Comment: В дополнение к указанному выше: socket, pipe, shared memory

Comment: Просто вводить с клавиатуры в цикле :)

Comment: Если вы *действительно хотите* менять аргументы командной строки (`argv[]` в main), то с некоторыми ограничениями можно использовать [gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305164/how-to-modify-memory-contents-using-gdb)

Answer (score 0):

Для, как Вы сказали "табло" нужно писать интерфейс.
Вот простой пример работы с консолью:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("* * * Enter the command, and click \"enter\": * * *\n\n'm': for send message 'm'\n'n': for send message 'n'\n'x': for exit\n");
        c = getchar();
        switch (c)
        {
        case 'm':
            printf("m: message m!\n");
            c = getchar();
            break;
        case 'n':
            printf("n: message n!\n");
            c = getchar();
            break;
        case 'x':
            printf("x: exit success!\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```